# Slow SELECT optimization with JOINs

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

My database consists of the following tables: articles, prices, suppliers, manufacturers and others.

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `suppliers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `manufacturers` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

With this query, I output all articles and join them to other tables. In order to filter the articles and prices according to the suppliers, i join the table "prices" to this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT articles.id 
              , manufacturers.name manufacturer_name
              ,
           FROM articles
           LEFT 
           JOIN manufacturers
             ON articles.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
           LEFT 
           JOIN prices
             ON articles.id = prices.article_id
```

This query works very slowly (about 6 seconds).

When I replace LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN, the output works super fast, but does not output items without prices.

```
INNER JOIN prices
    ON articles.id = prices.article_id
```

How can I optimize the query: articles with prices correctrly joining and quickly outputing?

Comment: Do your tables have any indexes?

Comment: This is not your query. But, if it were, it would be pointless to LEFT JOIN a table from which you select no columns. Also, note that the numbers in parentheses after `INT` are almost entirely meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you! The statement that the use of LEFT JOIN for the table, from which no columns are selected, would be pointless, has brought me to the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do is to **add indexes** to improve MySql performance.

[Mysql performance indexes explain](https://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-performance-indexes-explain/)